# Conditions to declare function deleted by c++

Tags: c++11, deleted-functions

ALL,

What are the conditions where the compiler itself declares the function deleted?

Consider following:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    virtual void func1() = 0;
    virtual void func2() = 0;
    virtual bool func3();
}

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    Bar(int param1);
    virtual void func1() override;
    virtual void func2() override;
    virtual bool func3() override;
}

class Baz
{
public:
    Baz(std::unique_ptr<Foo> &foo)
    {
        m_foo = foo;
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> m_foo;
}
```

I am getting a compiler error on the assignment (MSVC 2019):

```
attempting to reference a deleted function
```

This is compiled with C++11.

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to come from the line `m_foo = foo`

unique_ptr cannot be copied thus `unique_ptr& operator=(const unique_ptr&) is deleted`.

Unique pointers are about exclusive ownership. Thus, if you want to transfer ownership to baz, you will need to move the unique_ptr.

For example:

```
Baz(std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo) : m_foo{std::move(foo)}
{
}
```

For the conditions a compiler declares a special member deleted (by declared, we mean regular declaration or =default or =deleted):

- if a destructor or copy op or assignment op is declared then move operators are marked as deleted,
- if only one of the move operator is declared, the other one is marked as deleted,
- if a move copy op or a move assignment op is declared, the regular copy/assignment op are marked as deleted.

Comment: `std::move()` is C++14. I work with C++11. Also, I think I found the cause - `operator=(const std::unique_ptr &)` is marked as deleted in the documentation, I don't know how to fix it. (ref. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/operator=/)

Comment: `std::move` comes with c++11 and its move semantics. For the operator, as I said in the answer, it is intended. Maybe a shared ownership using `shared_ptr` is more suitable in your case?